# How to check either the headline or the content should contain "FIFA" keyword?

Tags: cypress

How do I write this test in Cypress?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDV2N.jpg)

I have to confirm that either the headline or paragraph should contain the same keyword.

Comment: Is it just one specifc header or paragraph you are trying to check?

Comment: Yes. First header and paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have JQuery elements in hand before the assertion so that you can use JQuery methods on them. `cy.get()` acts just like `$(...)` in JQuery, it will be enough to have the elements. (more [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Syntax))

Once u have the elements, i.e. `$el1` and `$el2` below, then you can get their text via `.text()` method (more [here](https://api.jquery.com/text/)) and then you can write your assertion.

Instead of a separate assertion, below I used a single one and checked if either of them includes the desired text by using `||` operator.

```js
  cy.get('first-el').then($el1 => {
    cy.get('second-el').then($el2 => {
      const inEl1 = $el1.text().includes('FIFA');
      const inEl2 = $el2.text().includes('FIFA');
      expect(inEl1 || inEl2).to.be.true;
    });
  });
```

Comment: See "[answer]" and [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.